# Where is the Default Program associations stored in the registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, file-association

If I run the `assoc` command-line utility for an extension, it shows the file type/description for the extension I set in the registry. But if I go to *Control Panel -> Default Programs - Set Associations* then I see a different description and default program.

It used to be that setting the two keys:

- `HKCR\.ext` (default) = *Identifier*
- *Identifier* (default) = "File Description"

  - \DefaultIcon (default) = *Some icon*
  - \Shell\Open\Command (default) = *Some editor*

But now it appears there is an override elsewhere, which is what gets displayed in the Default Programs listing.

My question is, where i this overridden association information stored? I'm assuming it is in the registry, but I don't see it in the keys I expect it to be. I believe this was changed in the Vista time frame, but it may have been in XP too.

**Update:** Since there is some confusion, do the following test. Rename a file to some new extension. Create an association in the registry keys mentioned above. Then right click on the file, *Open With* and select a different program (checking to make it the default). Now check the registry. It is unchanged, but now the file is associated with a different description, icon and default program.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Should be in:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes` and `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes`

And I don't believe that this has changed recently.

The priority is for current user, then local machine (aliased I believe to classes root).

Explorer uses a different set of registry keys that can be found at:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\`

Comment: I believe that is what `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` maps too. Those store what the `assoc` command returns. But the override information returned by *Default Programs* in the Control Panel is different.

Comment: I saw your edit about it being aliased to classes root. But you are missing the point that somewhere else there is overridden associations that are displayed in the *Default Programs* list from Control Panel.

Comment: and it is not the settings in HKCU?

Comment: Nope, see the update I added. You can test it yourself.

Comment: Explorer uses a different registry key

Comment: I was just looking in that 3rd place when you posted it. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome. Sorry about the earlier confusion.