# Internet Explorer command line behaviour

Tags: internet-explorer

I am developing an app which opens links, I started with always showing the 'Open As' dialog, but now adding the ability to specify a default in the program.

I pulled a [list of browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28172317/8348256) from the registry, but the noticed some strange behavior with IE.

If you Process.Start a URL with IE (eg. Start > Run > `www.superuser.com`) it will open in an existing IE window. (I have my Tabbed Browsing Settings set to Open links from other programs in: a new tab in the current window).

If you Process.Start IE with a URL (eg. Start > Run > `iexplore.exe "www.superuser.com"`) a new instance of IE will open with the URL.

As every other browser had the same behavior, I suspected it may be explained in the registry I checked my HKEY_CLASSES but couldn't find anything to explain the behavior.

I've looked at a few [other](https://superuser.com/q/436939/921955) [posts](https://superuser.com/q/1205914/921955) and even the [IE documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85)).

Have I missed anything in trying to **open IE links in an existing browser without having to override the default program?**